# How to set initial column width and make it not popping when typing in filter input in jquery plugin tablesorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

http://jsfiddle.net/ctgwqbpu/

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    widgets : ['zebra','resizable','stickyHeaders','filter'],

    widgetOptions: {
            resizable: true,
            resizable_widths : [ '195px', '20px', '40px', '100px', '200px' ]
        }

});
```

It does not work on firefox 45.2.0, CentOS 7. I am using latest forked version 2.28 https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter

Comment: I think I answered your questions in chat right?... essentially, set the [`widthFixed` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widthfixed) to `true`.